# Href link in controller with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new on Laravel and I would like to add an href link named listing (get via url->previous) with the user's message (inside 'body' below).

When a user contacts me through a page (form), I would like to add a link to that URL with the user's message, which would help me know where he contacted me.

MessageController.php:

```
// Message
    
    $target = url()->previous();  
    
    Message::create([
        'thread_id' => $thread->id,
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'body' => $input['message']. " - ".$target,
    ]);
```

Like that I get this when someone send a message:

[message from sender] - https://website.com/.... (just the Url of the previous page not link)

and I would like:

[message from sender] - [Listing](https://website.com/) (Link to the previous page)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Send the url to Controller using the link of your form by appanding the link ( /messageController/previous?=https://localhost/post/245 ) then us it in the controller.

Comment: doesn't work ! @Mehrwarz

Comment: can you share how you the link looks like and how you are getting the data in the controller?